# Why does $p \nmid m$ imply $\left(\frac{-4m^2} p\right) = \left(\frac{-1 } p\right)$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, legendre-symbol

$\newcommand{\Leg}[2]{\left(\frac{#1}{#2}\right)} $

Note: In this question $ a \mid b $ denotes *a divides b* and $\Leg a b$ denotes Legendre's symbol.

Theorem 9.12 in Introduction to Analytic Number Theory states:

> The Diophantine equation $$ y^2 = x^3 + k \tag{10} $$ has no solutions if $ k $ has the form $$ k = (4n - 1)^3 - 4m^2, \tag{11} $$ where $ m $ and $ n $ are integers such that no prime $ p \equiv -1 \pmod{4} $ divides $m$.

The proof is presented below. I have understood most of the proof except one sentence (the sentence before the last sentence).

> We assume a solution $x$, $y$ exists and obtain a contradiction by considering the equation modulo 4. Since $ k \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ we have $$ y^2 \equiv x^3 - 1 \pmod{4}. \tag{12}$$ Now $y^2 \equiv 0$ or $1$ $\pmod{4}$ for every y, so (12) cannot be satisfied if $x$ is even or if $x \equiv -1 \pmod{4}.$ Therefore we must have $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$. Now let $$ a = 4n - 1 $$ so that $ k = a^3 - 4m^2 $, and write (10) in the form $$ y^2 + 4m^2 = x^3 + a^3 = (x + a)(x^2 - ax + a^2). \tag{13}$$ Since $ x \equiv 1 \pmod{4} $ and $ a \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ we have $$ x^2 - ax + a^2 \equiv 1 - a + a^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{4}. \tag{14} $$
> Hence $ x^2 - ax + a^2 $ is odd, and (14) shows that all its prime factors cannot be $ \equiv 1 \pmod{4}.$ Therefore some prime $p \equiv -1 \pmod{4}$ divides $ x^2 - ax + a^2,$ and (13) shows that this also divides $y^2 + 4m^2.$ In other words,
> $$ y^2 \equiv -4m^2 \pmod{p} \text{ for some } p \equiv -1 \pmod{4}. \tag{15} $$
> But $ p \nmid m $ by hypothesis, so $\Leg{-4m^2}{p} = \Leg{-1} p = -1, $ contradicting (15). This proves that the Diophantine equation (10) has no solutions when $k$ has the form (11).

The part that I do not understand is this:

> But $ p \nmid m $ by hypothesis, so $\Leg{-4m^2} p  = \Leg{-1}p  $

Why does $ p \nmid m $ imply $\Leg{-4m^2} p = \Leg{-1} p $?

Comment: The Legendre symbol is multiplicative and $4m^2$ is obviously a square.

Comment: As a formatting note, why not use $\left(\frac ap\right)$ for the Legendre symbol?  That's \left(\frac ap\right)   I think that is more stanndard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this just follows from the multiplicative nature of the Legendre symbol.  Indeed,

$$\left(\frac {-4m^2}p\right)=\left(\frac {-1}p\right) \times \left(\frac {4m^2}p\right)=\left(\frac {-1}p\right)$$

Since $4m^2$ is, clearly, a non-zero square (trusting that $p>2$).